# Mock kafka producer in jUnit to test Future(Java)

Tags: java, apache-kafka

I am changing the implementation of how kafka sends events from async to sync

I found the following

```
 producer.send(producerRecord, (m, e) -> {
    ...some login...
 }).get();
 } catch (InterruptedException | RuntimeException | ExecutionException e) {
       logger.info("", e);
       throw new RuntimeException(e);
 }
```

I've added the get() method, which makes the code wait for a response before moving to the next one.

I now want to create a jUnit test to test this but I'm struggling to do so
I'm mocking the producer using Mockito
Then I'm using the following code

```
KafkaProducer mockProducer = Mockito.mock(KafkaProducer.class);
Future<RecordMetadata> future = Mockito.mock(Future.class);
doReturn(future).when(mockProducer).send(any());
when(future.get()).thenThrow(InterruptedException.class);
communicator.sendEvent(eventValue);//sendEvent then calls the producer and sends an event
```

I'm getting NullPointerException for some reason but when I evaluate producer.sendEvent and also producer.sendEvent(producerRecord).get() in the debugger. They both have values

So I'm not sure what's wrong.

any advice will be appreciated

PS: @cyberbrain Thank you for the example. Indeed, the issue was related with the mocking it incorrectly(I was passing one object instead of two)

```
when(mockProducer.send(any(),any())).thenReturn(future);
```

However, I have another problem. By mocking the provider with Mockito, it's not processing anything within the block

Example

```
producer.send(producerRecord, (m, e) -> {
  if(e!=null) then log this;
  else log this;
}).get();
```

I need to test the code inside the block but it's not letting me because I've mocked the object.

My understanding is that I could use the MockProducer provided by Kafka but that isn't helping either as I don't know how to mock the object that are sent inside the send method.

Comment: What is `future` in your test code? Why do you mix the methods of configuration of mocking in your test?

Comment: I've updated the code. Not sure what you mean about the mixup

Comment: Just to know, why are you mocking send(any())?  you are using in your code send with two parameters , one record and a function

Comment: On a different note, if you are using `Future.get()` in your code it's just as good (bad) as the previous synchronous code :/ That's not worth the effort then.

Comment: Please don't change your question for another problem, but rather open a new one. This is not a forum, but a Q&A platform where others can search for similar problems and find answers. (And make sure you link to this question otherwise the new one could be closed easily as duplicate)

Answer (score 0):

You do not mock the method that you call later (as @kiuby_88 already mentioned in a comment).

So you should do it in your test like this:

```java
KafkaProducer mockProducer = Mockito.mock(KafkaProducer.class);
Future<RecordMetadata> future = Mockito.mock(Future.class);

when(mockProducer).send(any(), any()).thenReturn(future);
when(future.get()).thenThrow(InterruptedException.class);

communicator.sendEvent(eventValue);
```

You mixed the `doReturn` style of Mockito configurations with the `when` style, which is confusing a bit. The `doReturn` style was introduced for setting up reactions on the call of methods returning `void` but can also be used to return values from other methods - but in my opinion it reduces confusion of the reader of you test-code, if you use one style throughout a whole test. An alternative style would be:

```java
doReturn(future).when(mockProducer).send(any(), any());
doThrow(InterruptedException.class).when(future).get();
```

See also the docs of Mockito about the [doReturn()|doThrow()| doAnswer()|doNothing()|doCallRealMethod() family of methods](https://javadoc.io/doc/org.mockito/mockito-core/latest/org/mockito/Mockito.html#12)

Comment: Thank you, I was passing one parameter instead of two, which didn't match the method I was testing. However I'm having a different issue and have updated my original post to explain that. Thank you again